# world city database (with lon,lat) & population per year

Tags: data, database, population

I'm building a visualisation with cities population around the globe for a website, found the MaxMind free database that includes most cities around the globe with coordinates and population, which is awesome. 
What I'd like to do is have something like a timeline, to show which cities have increased their population in the last years (even from 2005ish to 2012 would be great). 
I looked at the Maxmind site but couldn't find any older versions of their database. Do you know a place where I can find such a database? Thanks!

Comment: I think this Question may be better asked on the [**Open Data Stack Exchange**](http://opendata.stackexchange.com) (beta).  In any event this does not seem to be a GIS question since the data you are looking for is likely to be found in a non-spatial data format.

Comment: oh I'm sorry. I thought that since the database also contains latitude and longitude coordinates of the cities it could belong here. Should I move the question (how?) or just delete it?

Comment: You did not mention the presence of lat/long values in your Question but it is not too late to edit that into it.  With Open Data still only in Beta, I think you should post it there but perhaps leave it here too.  Normally, I am strongly against cross posting but when one site is Beta there is no guarantee that it will graduate and any valuable Q&A could be lost.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234495/how-to-ask-the-same-question-on-different-sites